# Sed and Awk Escaping Ampersands (&)

Tags: regex, shell

I'm parsing a PHP file and wrapping function prototype elements in HTML. If there are ampersands however, it breaks my code.

**Input**: `function foo (&$var1, &$var2){...}`//as String
**Desired output (in HTML)**: `&$var1, &$var2`  *//basically, just output the variables so that they are properly displayed in a browser*

Right now, I am sending each variable into awk's sub method<sup>**1**</sup>, and then to sed.

```
sub(/^&/, "\\\&", param)  #param is the variable of interest (e.g. &$var1)

#Intermediate step in case it's relevant. The awk-processed elements 
#are sent to ${file}_param.txt. Each set of parameters are delimited by colons.
param=$(cut -d: -f$counter ${file}_param.txt) 

#Replace some default text in template file with real stuff.
sed -i "s|@PARAM|$param|1" "$base"_funct_def.txt
```

**Output I'm getting:** The ampersands are being interpreted. The entire match is replaced.

**Isolation of issue:** Doing the following instead displays 'g$var1' in the browser as  I want it to. However, I'm trying to get an '&' instead.

```
sub(/^&/, "g", param)
```

**My attempts:** I used three backslashes because I thought awk would first process it into '\&' which, fed into sed, would interpret '\&' as the literal '&'. I have tried anywhere from 1 to 6 backslashes though, to no avail.

**QUESTION:** How can I escape the &?

<sup>**1**</sup>Manual: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html

---

*Some "meta"/design questions about what I'm trying to do (not needed for question!!)*
I have bunch of PHP files that I'm trying to generate a bit of documentation for (structured like Javadocs). I'm going through and parsing it using REGEX and shell scripts, so that I list out the function name, parameters, and return item(s). So far, REGEX has worked out pretty well I think, but I have read a lot about how this is something that REGEX should NOT be used for. I'd welcome any comments about any of this (how is documentation usually generated?). Thanks guys!

Comment: What does `$param` actually contain? If the commands aren't run sequentially (e.g. if there are actually some other codes in between), you shouldn't put them in the same code block, it's misleading.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading part. I'll keep that in mind in the future.
$param contains a parameter element. For example, if there's a function:
`function foo(&$arg1, $arg2)`
$param is supposed to be `'&$arg1'`

Good news though: I found a fix. Before executing sed, I made sure to escape any '&'. I added the following right after the first param assignment:
`param=$(echo $param | sed 's|^&|\\&|g')`

This is as opposed to trying to wrap things in the awk portion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using two backslashes (i.e. `sub(/^&/, "\\&", param)`) works for me. Doesn't it work for you?

It is documented in [the nawk manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) you referred to in your question:

> As usual, to insert one backslash in the string, you must write two backslashes. Therefore, write `\\&' in a string constant to include a literal `&' in the replacement

Also, your `sub()` function is essentially replacing an ampersand with an ampersand. So maybe that's why you think it's not working even with two backslashes.

Comment: Did it work after sending the output of sub to sed? I think sub is outputting a literal '&', but when it is passed to sed, the '&' is interpreted once again. So for sub, I'm actually trying to output '\&', so that it gets escaped in the sed portion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe HTML reads `&amp;` as the ampersand character. In your awk script you could use:

```
sub(/^&/, "&amp;", param)
```

The dollar sign in `param` needs to be escaped with a backslash, e.g. &$var needs to be written as &\$var, or sed and awk will try to expand $var as a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's the issue. Replacing it with "&amp" will still be interpreted by awk and sed as the REGEX '&', which duplicates the matched item in the output. (I did try what you suggested just as a sanity check. Didn't work out.)

Comment: I changed my answer after doing some testing. The un-escaped dollar signs seem to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` method:

```
printf "%s\n" 'function foo (&$var1, &$var2){...}//as String' | 
sed -n '/function/{s/^.*(//;s/).*$//;p}'
```

Output:

```
&$var1, &$var2
```

Or if HTML code is needed, pass that to a util like [`txt2html`](http://txt2html.sourceforge.net):

```
printf "%s\n" 'function foo (&$var1, &$var2){...}//as String' | 
sed -n '/function/{s/^.*(//;s/).*$//;p}' | txt2html
```